# Running Automation on Google Cloud Virtual Instances using Ansible

Tags: ansible, google-cloud-platform, ssh

I'm trying to automate google cloud virtual instances remotely only using external ip addresses of virtual machines. I can ssh into the virtual machines using command line with user name `shishir9159_gmail_com` . But If I use any ansible commands like this:

```
ansible -i hosts -u shishir9159_gmail_com --private-key=~/.ssh/google_compute_engine -m ping all
```

and it results in this following error:

```
"msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: shishir9159@35.202.219.6: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)."
```

I've used some parameters in my ansible.cfg:

```
host_key_checking = False
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=no
```

But I don't think they do much of a help according to this post:
https://serverfault.com/questions/929222/ansible-where-do-preferredauthentications-ssh-settings-come-from

And I tried many methods and recommendations. I have a service account but it doesn't seem to me necessary for this simple ping command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding `ansible_ssh_user` and `ansible_ssh_pass` at the hosts file. This post contain the solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213551/ansible-ssh-connection-fail?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You run the command with the user `shishir9159_gmail_com` but the error shows `shishir9159@35.202.219.6: Permission denied` ... seems like the `_gmail_com` portion of the username is truncated. Can you try setting the `ansible_user` config parameter in your inventory file or playbook rather than passing it on via the CLI?

Comment: I tried as ansible_user and ssh_user too in "ansible.cfg". But with "-vvvv" parameter (that shows verbose in details), it's always showing Connecting to host 35.202.219.6 for user shishir9159. I don't know how to change this...